# How to make swiper.js slider (Thumbs Gallery) display as block instead of inline

Tags: javascript, html, css

when I put it inside a div or a section or whatever that is a block, it disappears and of course i'd like to add some margins and padding and stuff but it is inline.

I've tried changing the css display to block of every single class and element and to inline block but it just wont work out. i've also tried to put images inside the div and try to acomodate with object fit and object position but still not display as a block. I've already lost 4 hours looking for a solution on my own but i feel i can't no more...

this is the code

html

```
<!-- Swiper -->
  <div class="swiper-container gallery-top swiper2">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide ss2" style="background-image:url(/img/hero.jpg)"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide ss2" style="background-image:url(/img/hero.jpg)"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide ss2" style="background-image:url(/img/hero.jpg)"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide ss2" style="background-image:url(/img/hero.jpg)"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- Add Arrows -->
    <div class="swiper-button-next swiper-button-white"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev swiper-button-white"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-container gallery-thumbs">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide ss2" style="background-image:url(/img/hero.jpg)"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide ss2" style="background-image:url(/img/hero.jpg)"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide ss2" style="background-image:url(/img/hero.jpg)"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide ss2" style="background-image:url(/img/hero.jpg)"></div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Swiper JS -->
```

javascript

```
var galleryThumbs = new Swiper('.gallery-thumbs', {
            spaceBetween: 10,
            slidesPerView: 3,
            freeMode: true,
            watchSlidesVisibility: true,
            watchSlidesProgress: true,
          });
          var galleryTop = new Swiper('.gallery-top', {
            spaceBetween: 10,
            navigation: {
              nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
              prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
            },
            thumbs: {
              swiper: galleryThumbs
            }
          });
```

css

```
.ss2 {
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
  }

  .gallery-top {
    height: 70%;
    width: 60%;
  }

  .gallery-thumbs {
    height: 10%;
    width: 60%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px 0;
  }

  .gallery-thumbs .swiper-slide {
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.4;
  }

  .gallery-thumbs .swiper-slide-thumb-active {
    opacity: 1;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can assume that the problem is positioning of html elements. As you said swiper displays as an inline instead of a block whenever you put it into a container or so. What I would suggest to try is to give a parent element of the swiper `position: relative` and set container position to `position: relative` as well. This will make child elements treat it as a base for their positions that you have set. If it does not solve your problem can you provide an example of how does the code work now (via jsfiddle for example)